# $f$ is measurable and $g$ is monotonic continuous, is $f \circ g$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function on real numbers and $g$ is a monotonic continuous function on real numbers. Is the function composition $f \circ g$ Lebesgue measurable? Thanks.

Comment: I give the standard counterexample in my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283443/is-composition-of-measurable-functions-measurable/283548#283548

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is no. But if you have an extra condition that $g^{-1}$ is Lipschitz, the answer is yes.

Recall that, if $h$ is Lipschitz, then $\mu(A) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu(h(A)) = 0$ (you can try proving this). Now we can express $f^{-1}(A)$ as a disjoint union of $B$ and $C$ where $B$ is borel measurable and $C$ has measure zero. So we will have,

$$f \circ g \, (A) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(A)) = g^{-1}(B \cup C) = g^{-1}(B) \cup g^{-1}(C)$$

$g^{-1}(B)$ is borel and  $g^{-1}(C)$ has measure zero since $g^{-1}$ is Lipschitz, hence proving that $f \circ g$ is measurable.

Comment: is condition of Lipschitz necessary?

Comment: @safa: Yes - if you want the composition to be measurable.

Comment: let for any set measure zero example C ,function g inverse C be Lebesgue measurable. is composition fog Lebesgue measurable? thanks

Comment: @safa: What has this got to do with the composition being lebesgue measurable. Can you clarify as to which part of the solution are you referring to?

Comment: @safa: That's exactly my point. The statement in the current form that you have stated is not true. Only with the lipschitz assumption is it true. And $g^{-1}$ taking null sets to null sets is an off shoot of the assumption. In general why would $g^{-1}$ take map null sets to null sets. I have not come across any property that would make it do so. If there is any, do let me know.

Comment: pondy:Suppose the above question (the first question I asked) is given. Which of the following options is correct?
1 - If the function g is strictly monotonic, then the composition (fog) Lebesgue measurable.
2 - if for any null set C, function g-l(C) be Lebesgue measurable, then composition (fog) is measurable.  
 This question is my phd exam. many Thanks for the your answer

Comment: @safa: 1 - False, 2 - True